# More General way (tag-agnostic) to Grab Education and other unstructured data from multiple websites?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am examining this website: http://www.weil.com/michaelfrancies/

I wonder if there are better ways to grab data, like their education or expertise area, than the following. My goal is to make my program as general as possible, so that it would work for any biography page on the web.

Should I be trying to use nltk?

```
 #What happens if I don't specify any tags?
for i in dom:
    sib = str(i)
    #print len(sib)
    if len(sib) <= 100:
        for c in uni:
            if c in sib:
                collect.append(sib.strip())

np.unique(filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 100, collect))
```

sorry to clarify: 
I know how to use paths using pattern and requests. However, I'd like a general scraping tool that can work for many websites. It appears that for programs that use paths, you have to pre-name tags and classes to search?

For instance, one some websites, the education section is under the 'p' tag, in others, it's under 'br'

output

```
array([ 'Manchester University (LL.B.,&nbsp;1978);&nbsp;College of Law, London (LSF,&nbsp;1979)'], 
      dtype='|S86')
```

UPDATE.

Comment: This looks like python (add a python tag if true). Parsing HTML with regex is often problematic and using a library specifically designed to parse HTML will help a lot. If you are using python I'd suggest looking into something like beautifulsoup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup

Comment: sorry to clarify: I know how to use paths using pattern and requests. However, I'd like a general scraping tool that can work for many websites. It appears that for programs that use paths, you have to pre-name tags and classes to search?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) with xpath:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>>
>>> tree = lxml.html.parse('http://www.weil.com/michaelfrancies/')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> [x.tail.strip() for x in root.xpath('.//span[text()="Education"]/following-sibling::br')]
[u'Manchester University (LL.B.,\xa01978);\xa0College of Law, London (LSF,\xa01979)']
```

complete xpath:

```
.//span[text()="Education" or text()="Academic qualifications" or text()="LL.B"]/following-sibling::br
```

Comment: I apologize. My question was not specific enough. Can you check it out again?